# ZF3 - Populate Select from Database

Tags: database, select, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm doing some work using Zend Framework 3 and I need to display in the form a select populated with options comming from the database. I am using SQL Abstraction used in the Zend Tutorial blog part. The idea is to show the form that is already build and add a simple select with data returned from a different table, all the form is working using the users table (which has the country id) and i would like to link that id to the correct table and then show all the countries in the select..

Thank's everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You will write a factory for your form. Select data in that factory and pass to form via `construct` or some `set` method, and use that data as value options.

```
class MyFormFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function __invoke($container, $options) {
         $data = []; // call repository via $container and fetch your data
         $form = new MyForm();

         $form->setCountries($data);

         return $form;
    }
}

class MyForm extends \Zend\Form\Form {
    private $countries = [];

    public function setCountries(array $countries) {
         $this->countries = $countries;
    }

    public function init(){
         $this->add([
             'type' => Select::class,
             'name' => 'countries',
             'options' => [
                  'label' => 'Countries',
                  'value_options' => $this->countries
             ]
         ]);
    }
}
```

and put your form under factories key in config

```
return [
     'form_elements' => [
          'factories' => [
              MyForm::class => MyFormFactory::class
          ]
     ]
];
```

Now when you call your form over `FormElementManager`, your factory will trigger, it will call repository and fetch data, pass it to your form.

Don't forget to add `Zend\Form` in your modules config.

This approach works well with zf3.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Can we contact by email plz? Thank you.

Comment: I am using two different tabels.. Users and Countries and that's why I can't get this to work tho :/

Comment: Doesn't matter. You see `$data` variable in factory, put your countries in this variable as `key => value` pairs. If you can create a gist i can edit it.

Comment: Sure, 1 min and i post github so you can take a look if you can :)

Comment: What I am currently doing is the "Distrito" select, not countries, we changed that to distrito. It's in the module Influenciador.

Comment: can you help me out plz?